# ¿me aparece un error y no se como solucionarlo?

Tags: visual-studio, gulp-sass

> Error: 'win32-x64' binaries cannot be used on the 'darwin-x64' platform. Please remove the 'node_modules/sharp' directory and run 'npm install' on the 'darwin-x64' platform.

Comment: Y ese error sale por arte de magia o haces algo? Pásate por [ask] y realiza el [tour], luego [edit] tu pregunta para ser más conciso.

Answer (score 1):

usualmente esto sucede en los usuarios de MAC, puedes intentar los siguientes comandos:

```
rm -rf node_modules/sharp
npm install --arch=x64 --platform=darwin sharp
```

Comment: Lo probare, muchas gracias.